# Multipling 2 strings together

Tags: java, string, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two simple strings together for a class of mine. The program itself is to show gross pay based on the hourly rate and hours worked, entered by the user. I've done some digging but the results I've found, seem overly complicated for what I'm trying to achieve. Granted I'm coming from C# to Java so I acknowledge there are differences. The following is the code that I have so far.

```
    String RoPString, hrswrkdString;

    double grosspay, netpay, whtax;

    //Rate of pay input dialog box.
    RoPString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter employee's hourly rate", "Rate of Pay", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Hours worked input dialog box.
    hrswrkdString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter hours worked", "Hours Worked", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    //Calculations
    grosspay = RoPString*hrswrkdString;

    //Summary of pay
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gross Pay: $" + grosspay);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grosspay = RoPString*hrswrkdString;
```

You can't apply `*` operator on `String` types. Convert `String` to `double` and then do `*`.

Example:

```
  double ropdouble = Double.valueOf(RoPString);
  double hrswrkddouble = Double.valueOf(hrswrkdString);
```

Note: Follow Java naming convention while naming variables (variable name starts with lower case).

Comment: Since when is the type part of the naming convention?

Comment: @EmilVikström: I didn't mean that. I meant variable name starts with lower case letter. Added clarification. I know type is not part of convention and it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use `Double.parseDouble()` to get the `String` objects into something that will work with multiplication.

```
String RoPString, hrswrkdString;
double grosspay, netpay, whtax;

//Rate of pay input dialog box.
RoPString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter employee's hourly rate", "Rate of Pay", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

//Hours worked input dialog box.
hrswrkdString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter hours worked", "Hours Worked", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

//Calculations
grosspay = Double.parseDouble(RoPString)*Double.parseDouble(hrswrkdString);

//Summary of pay
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gross Pay: $" + grosspay.toString());
```

}